Android Studio Find in Files is not finding files
I open my Android Studio multi-module project and open the Find In Files dialog. InProject is selected and there's no filters so it should search everything. I enter the search string fsId(s and it finds a bunch of instances. Then I remove the final s in the search string and some of those instances disappear! They are not found at all even though anything that contains fsId(s also contains fsId(. The same problem happens with fsId, so its not a problem with the parenthesis. It appears to only return results from one module unless I include the final s, in which case it searches everywhere.
This makes me believe that the Find In Files feature is horribly broken in...
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.4.1

Also, I changed the scope to Module, selected a module, then pasted in a string from a file in that module. Zero results! I try it again with another string from the same line of code... results found!!
My confidence in the Find in Files feature is eroding. Has anyone else had this problem?  Was this fixed in a later version?

I found the answer. There is an advanced setting that limits the maximum number of search results and defaults to 100. Yes, only 100. I changed that to a more reasonable 50000 and it worked.

your answer is correct , i suggest you mark it as the correct one .
thanks

settings - advanced settings - find / replace
